# ggplot faceting - remove empty x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I' using faceting following this [article](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2/) except for using a certain subset of the data removing some rows.

```
# create a dataset
specie=c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition=rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value=abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data=data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# remove some rows
data=data[c(1:2,5:6,7,9,11:12),]

# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

# Faceting
ggplot(data, aes(y=value, x=specie, color=specie, fill=specie)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity") +    
  facet_wrap(~condition)
```

This gives the following plot as expected. I need to remove the empty labels from each of the plots below - for example, `sorgho` from first, `poacee` and `triticum` from second and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `scales` argument to `facet_wrap()`. Try

```
# Faceting
ggplot(data, aes(y=value, x=specie, color=specie, fill=specie)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity") +    
  facet_wrap(~condition, scales = "free")
```