# Facet grid: keeping order when removing empty rows (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facet wrap with empty areas that I want to remove (standard answer: set scales = free_y (check e.g.: [ggplot faceting - remove empty x-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960539/ggplot-faceting-remove-empty-x-axis-labels) )) as well as I want a specified order for all my faceting variables (here "d"). 
However it seems like I have to chooose:

either ordered or empty areas removed.

But: **I want both, my order as well as, empty rows removed.**

Here is example code:

```
#gen some example code
c <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
d <- c('firstsecond', 'firstfirst', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower')
e <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
f <- c('w', 'v','w', 'v')
df <- cbind(c,d,e,f)
df<- as.data.frame(df)
df$e <- as.numeric(df$e)
orderd <- c( 'firstfirst', 'firstsecond', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower' )
df<- within(df, d <- factor(d, levels=orderd))

#plotting it with the desired order:
plot_e1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = 15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free_y", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  #by the way: why do I need to reverse it with rev() ?
  scale_x_discrete(drop=TRUE, limits = rev(levels(df$d)))+
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2)

plot_e1 #right side of attachjed picture

#plotting it with the emptry areas removed:
plot_e2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = 15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free_y", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$d)))+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=TRUE)+
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2)
# and the warning message is an added bonus of this stupid version :( )
```

plot_e2 #left side of attachjed picture

[image: A picture that shows both problems]

Comment: What is your desired result?  Please post screenshot possibly using an image software.

Comment: I like to have the order from the right plot (called "correct order"), upper part of code, and the omission of the empty rows (right plot, lower part of code). Sorry, what is wrong with the picture? I dont think I have any image software, thank you, any advice appreciated.

Comment: This is a weird result as `facet_wrap` should preserve factor order. Also, the `scale_x_discrete` lines of *plot_e2* is redundant. Consider adding a ticket in [ggplot2's Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues) using same reproducible example and after searching for any dups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what creates the issue, but this seems to fix it.

First, reversing the levels of the factor in the df:

```r
orderd <- rev(c( 'firstfirst', 'firstsecond', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower' ))
df<- within(df, d <- factor(d, levels=orderd))
```

Then this code returns the plot with the right order and no gaps:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = 15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2)
```

Comment: Dear aaumai Thank you so much! I wonder why one has to reverse the order in the first place. Why is reversing needed at all? Because of the coord_flip? 

`scale= "free"` makes the axis odd, they are not aligned anymore, why I will continue to use `free_y` which also works perfectly. Thanks a lot!